# ajax ($.post) то работает, то нет (в некоторых браузерах)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Есть код `ajax` который работает с помощью библиотеки `jquery`:

```
$(window).bind('unload', function() {

$.post(
  "/acur.php",
  {
    unload: 0,
    compare: ID
  },
  onSuccess
);

function onSuccess(data)
{
  console.log(data);
}

});
```

Т.е. по коду когда мы закрываем вкладку, то `ajax` должен передать через файл `acur.php` в `mysql` данные.
В chrome всегда работает, а вот в operе и mozillе иногда может не сработать.

В чем здесь проблема?

Comment: откройте в этих браузерах консоль и посмотрите ошибки, что там?

Comment: В консоле чисто (даже предупреждении нет). Непонятно даже в какую сторону смотреть: то ли ajax глючит, то ли mysql прерывается, то ли банально из-за событии jquery unload, который возможно в некоторых браузерах не очень хорошо работает

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Функциональность отправки ajax запросов в обработчике события отгрузки страницы считается устаревшей уже несколько лет. Резон здесь тот, что ajax запрос подразумевает получение ответа, который придет, когда страницы уже не будет. К счастью, вместо этого можно пользоваться функцией `navigator.sendBeacon`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/sendBeacon